# Cakephp: issue with permissions when using the Apc cache

Tags: cakephp, apc

When using the file cache, this config let me write/read the cache from a shell script

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'mask' => 0666
));
```

However, when using something like this

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'Apc',
    'mask' => 0666 // I don't think this is used by Apc cache.
));
```

I get permission errors when saving/reading the cache from a shell script. The Apc cache is working fine when running from regular page loads though. I understand that shell scripts aren't executed from the same user as regular page loads, but I don't know how to set the Apc cache permissions correctly.

Here's my shell script:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {      
    public function main(){ 
        Cache::write('Hello', 5);
    }
}
```

Here's the error

```
Warning Error: default cache was unable to write 'hello' to Apc cache in [/home/pi/MyProject/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 325]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable APC for php-cli 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enable-cli
because shell jobs runs as command line php

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just answered your question. Have you tried changing the permissions of the App/tmp/ directory to 777?

```
#chmod -R 777 app/tmp
```

Comment: My app/tmp directory is set to 777 recursively. And File Cache works fine too. My question is about Apc cache. From my understanding, the Apc cache is not storing files in app/tmp.

Comment: I did not knew about cli. It effectively solved my problem. Thanks for your help.